# How to access app container in ember cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an object foo:

```
name: 'foo',
initialize: function (registry, application) {
    application.register("foo:main", Ember.Object.extend({bar: Ember.inject.service()}), {
        singleton: false,
        instantiate: false
    });
}
```

**Bar** has default register options, so *singleton* and *instantiate*.
**Foo** is registered via a container because I would not be able to inject bar otherwise. Hence, `Ember.inject.service` can only be used on objects which are wrapped within the container.

I would like to extend from foo within a single file and export the resulted class similar to:

```
import App from 'my-app/app';

export default App.container.lookup('foo:main').extend({
```

*This won't work since app.js does not export the application instance.*

How can I access app container in Ember CLI?